# Is it possible to align the results in the quickfix list in columns

Tags: quickfix, alignment, rearrangement

Currently, when I view the quickfix list with `:cw`, the columns/pipes are not aligned, as in this example:

[image]

I wonder if there is an option in vim or a plugin to rearrange the pipes so that they align in columns. [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim) does something similar for csv files (see gif in the README).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more searching yielded [the qf-layout plugin](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-qf-layout), which is working great in my initial tests!

In order to show only the basename instead of the entire filepath, I modified [line 84](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-qf-layout/blob/master/autoload/vim_addon_qf_layout.vim#L84) from

```
let l.filename = bufname(l.bufnr)
```

to

```
let l.filename = fnamemodify(bufname(l.bufnr), ":t")
```

It looks neat!

[image]

In case someone else finds this useful, I recommend adding something like the following to your `.vimrc`, and put the formatting you prefer first in the list. I changed from `'NOP'` to `'vim_addon_qf_layout#DefaultFormatter'`:

```
let g:vim_addon_qf_layout = {}
let g:vim_addon_qf_layout.quickfix_formatters = [
    \'vim_addon_qf_layout#DefaultFormatter',
    \'vim_addon_qf_layout#FormatterNoFilename',
    \'vim_addon_qf_layout#Reset',
    \'NOP' ]
```

PS This plugin works great together with the [SpellCheck plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SpellCheck) which populates the quickfix list with misspelled words!

Answer (score 5):

If your Vim includes the patch [8.2.0959](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0959), you can set the `'quickfixtextfunc'` option to the name of a Vimscript function whose task is to format each entry displayed in the quickfix window.

To get the desired alignment, use a few `printf()` invocations appropriately.

As an example:

```
set qftf=QuickFixTextFunc nowrap | syn on
fu QuickFixTextFunc(info) abort
    if a:info.quickfix
        let qfl = getqflist(#{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
    else
        let qfl = getloclist(a:info.winid, #{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
    endif
    let l = []
    let lnum_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> qfl[v].lnum})
        \ ->max()
        \ ->len()
    let col_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> qfl[v].col})
        \ ->max()
        \ ->len()
    let fname_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> qfl[v].bufnr->bufname()->fnamemodify(':t')->strchars(1)})
        \ ->max()
    let type_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> get(s:EFM_TYPE, qfl[v].type, '')->strlen()})
        \ ->max()
    let errnum_width = range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        \ ->map({_, v -> qfl[v].nr})
        \ ->max()
        \ ->len()
    for idx in range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        let e = qfl[idx]
        if !e.valid
            call add(l, '|| ' .. e.text)
        else
            if e.lnum == 0 && e.col == 0
                call add(l, bufname(e.bufnr))
            else
                let fname = printf('%-*S', fname_width, bufname(e.bufnr)->fnamemodify(':t'))
                let lnum = printf('%*d', lnum_width, e.lnum)
                let col = printf('%*d', col_width, e.col)
                let type = printf('%-*S', type_width, get(s:EFM_TYPE, e.type, ''))
                let errnum = ''
                if e.nr
                    let errnum = printf('%*d', errnum_width + 1, e.nr)
                endif
                call add(l, printf('%s|%s col %s %s%s| %s', fname, lnum, col, type, errnum, e.text))
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    return l
endfu
const s:EFM_TYPE = #{e: 'error', w: 'warning', i: 'info', n: 'note'}
helpg foobar
copen
```

---

If you care about speed, and you often deal with long quickfix lists, try to rewrite the code in Vim9 script:

```
vim9script
set qftf=QuickFixTextFunc nowrap | syn on
def QuickFixTextFunc(info: dict<number>): list<string>
    var qfl: list<any>
    if info.quickfix
        qfl = getqflist({id: info.id, items: 0}).items
    else
        qfl = getloclist(info.winid, {id: info.id, items: 0}).items
    endif
    var l: list<string> = []
    var lnum_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v: number): number => qfl[v].lnum)
        ->max()
        ->len()
    var col_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v: number): number => qfl[v].col)
        ->max()
        ->len()
    var fname_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v: number): number => qfl[v].bufnr->bufname()->fnamemodify(':t')->strchars(true))
        ->max()
    var type_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v: number): number => get(EFM_TYPE, qfl[v].type, '')->strlen())
        ->max()
    var errnum_width: number = range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        ->map((_, v: number): number => qfl[v].nr)
        ->max()
        ->len()
    for idx in range(info.start_idx - 1, info.end_idx - 1)
        var e: dict<any> = qfl[idx]
        if !e.valid
            add(l, '|| ' .. e.text)
        else
            if e.lnum == 0 && e.col == 0
                add(l, bufname(e.bufnr))
            else
                var fname: string = printf('%-*S', fname_width, bufname(e.bufnr)->fnamemodify(':t'))
                var lnum: string = printf('%*d', lnum_width, e.lnum)
                var col: string = printf('%*d', col_width, e.col)
                var type: string = printf('%-*S', type_width, get(EFM_TYPE, e.type, ''))
                var errnum = ''
                if e.nr
                    errnum = printf('%*d', errnum_width + 1, e.nr)
                endif
                add(l, printf('%s|%s col %s %s%s| %s', fname, lnum, col, type, errnum, e.text))
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    return l
enddef
const EFM_TYPE = {e: 'error', w: 'warning', i: 'info', n: 'note'}
helpg foobar
copen
```

On my machine, it seems to be around 4 times faster.

This requires a recent Vim version. It works on 8.2.2332.

---

For more info, see:

- [`:h 'qftf'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27qftf%27)
- [`:h quickfix-window-function`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-window-function)
- [`:h vim9`](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html)
- [`:h :def`](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html#:def)