# Remove full path from quickfix list when using vimgrep

Tags: quickfix, vimgrep

I use VIM 7.4.
When I want to search some text in my project, i use following command:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/j *.c *.h
```

Then I use `:cw` command to open quickfix list for getting search results.

Here is my problem.
Sometimes quickfix displays something like:

```
main.c|71 col 5| u8 pattern = 0;
```

It's okay.
But sometimes it displays full path:

```
Users\user\dir1\dir2\etc\etc\etc\project\main.c|71 col 5| u8 pattern = 0;
```

And it becomes impossible to use quickfix comfortably because file path "ate" the whole horizontal space.

What can I do to get rid of full paths in quickfix list? What alternatives could you recommend for "in-project" search?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: If you upgrade Vim, then you could leverage the [module property](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setqflist-what) of quickfix entries, or the [`'quickfixtextfunc'` option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'qftf').

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom quickfixtextfunc to customize the results.
See `:help quickfix-window-function` for more details.  Using the [answer to this more involved customization](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/is-it-possible-to-align-the-results-in-the-quickfix-list-in-columns) as a guide, you can do the following to set the results to just the text strings:

```
set quickfixtextfunc=QFTextOnly

func QFTextOnly(info) 
    if a:info.quickfix
        let qfl = getqflist(#{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
    else
        let qfl = getloclist(a:info.winid, #{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
    endif
    let l = []
    for idx in range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
        call add(l, substitute(qfl[idx].text, '^\s*','',''))
    endfor
    return l
endfunc
```